# awk (or sed or grep) to cut parametr, equal sign and value

Tags: linux, awk, sed, grep

I am newbie in Linux. When I run such command

```
 ps -ef | grep 5312
```

system shows me all info about process with PID 5312. For example, output looks like

```
tomcat    5312     1  0 20:03 ?        00:00:09 /usr/lib/jvm/jre/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/opt/tomcat/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048 -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources -Xms500M -Xmx700M -server -XX:+UseParallelGC -classpath /opt/tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar:/opt/tomcat/bin/tomcat-juli.jar -Dcatalina.base=/opt/tomcat -Dcatalina.home=/opt/tomcat -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/tomcat/temp org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start
```

From such output I want to know only "tmpdir=/opt/tomcat/temp" parametr. I need only tmpdir, equal sign and a value after equal sign. How can I do it with sed or awk (or maybe grep)?

Answer (score 3):

Use `grep` with the `-o` option to return just the matching part.

```
ps -ef | grep 5312 | grep -o 'tmpdir=[^ ]*'
```

Comment: I suggest to add option `-w` (Select only those lines containing matches that form whole words) to first `grep`.

Comment: I'm guessing that's simplified for the example and not really relevant. He should probably use `pgrep`, because even with that fix it will also match the `grep` command itself.

Comment: We can eliminate the second grep by using: ```ps -p 5312 -eh | grep -o 'tmpdir=[^ ]*'```

Comment: Like I said, I suspect that's simplified and he may not actually be searching for a known PID.

Answer (score -1):

since you asked for awk:

```
ps -ef|grep -v awk|awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i ~ /tmpdir/){print $i}}}' | awk -F'.' '{print $NF}'
```

where:

`ps -ef`: Shows all process.

`grep -v awk`: Makes you sure to not show your own awk process.

`for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)`: Will loop through all fields of current record until [last field](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Auto_002dset) is reached.

`if($i ~ /tmpdir/){print $i}}`: Since you're *looping* through fields if current contains key string "tmpdir" will print it (the field).

`awk -F'.' '{print $NF}'`: You requested only tmpdir parameter, so you want everything in the last field having a dot as field separator.